# Gradient Input in Game view

Tags: unity, gui, input, unity-ui

I want to develop a little tool to help visualize fireworks before using them in a show in Unity where the user can set several parameters and gets a preview of the firework effect in a preview window. To allow the user to customize color over time like I can currently statically do in the visual effects graph, I wanted to add a Gradient input field to my UI.

After fiddling around with manually trying to make things work, I stumbled upon the new UIElements / UI Toolkit and following [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@raynor85/new-unity-uielements-runtime-system-how-to-use-it-now-f560c4cb22d2) was able to render a simple text UI in a Panel Renderer. However the Gradient Field I added won't show up (which is quite reasonable because in the UI Builder it said something about "Editor only").

Just to make sure, the box on the left is what I mean:

[image: Screenshot showing a sample editor window with a gradient input, the HDR Gradient Editor and HDR Color Selector]

I was strolling around in the Asset Store for a while but couldn't find anything like what I was looking for (just shaders and stuff to apply a gradient to UI elements amongst other things). Other searches led to tutorials on how to completely custom build a single color selection tool which both seemed like a larger effort and didn't allow creating a full gradient.

The question is: Is there some sort of library, package or tool I could use to add an input like that to my "game"? Or am I taking a completely wrong approach with this?

Comment: It looks to me like you'll have to re-implement this functionality in your game code, if it's not part of the Unity runtime but solely in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I am utterly bad at googling things! While "unity gradient input" and several attempts at going at it from UIElements and UI Toolkit didn't yield result, a brainfart reminded me that the thing you select a color in is called a color picker and look at that, there actually *is* an implementation of both a color and gradient picker available for free in the [Easy Color & Gradient Picker](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/gui/easy-color-gradient-picker-176831).

It comes with a handy PDF telling you how to set up things and while intensity is not part of the input, building the gradient comes very close to the editor built in controls:

[image: Screenshot of the gradient picker implemented by the Easy Color & Gradient picker]